# Sharepoint WCF service CustomBinding with binaryMessageEncoding

Tags: wcf, sharepoint

I've been doing tests using the following sample from Microsoft :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521581.aspx

it works, but it is a basichttp endpoint.

is there a way to make it a CustomBinding endpoint with binaryMessageEncoding?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

This will create a custom binding using Http transport and binary encoding:

```
protected override Binding CreateBinding()
{
    BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement messageEncoding = new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement();
    TransportBindingElement transport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();

    BindingElementCollection bindingElements = new BindingElementCollection()
    {
        messageEncoding, transport
    };

    return new CustomBinding(bindingElements);
}
```

Comment: ok but this is on the client side. I need to "configure" my service at the server side. Can I do that with Property Attributes?

Comment: In general WCF, it's quite straightforward. In SharePoint, I don't know. What do you mean by Property Attributes? Are you talking about the web.config?

Comment: I mean class attributes... like [BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpointAttribute]